# SYBASE ASE: The 'lockf' call failed for database/archive device while working on stripe device with error number 37 (No locks available)

Tags: database, sybase, dump, sap-ase, nfs

I'm trying to do a sybase database dump to a NFS location but encounters the following error below

```
1> use master
2> go
1> dump database FIP to '/ddbackup/FIP/dump/test3.dmp'
2> stripe on '/ddbackup/FIP/dump/test3.dmp.S1.dmp'
3> stripe on '/ddbackup/FIP/dump/test3.dmp.S2.dmp' with compression=100
4> go
Backup Server: 4.172.1.4: The value of 'allocated pages threshold' has been set to 40%.
Backup Server session id is: 29. Use this value when executing the 'sp_volchanged' system stored procedure after fulfilling any volume change request from the Backup Server.
Backup Server: 4.41.1.1: Creating new disk file /ddbackup/FIP/dump/test3.dmp.
Backup Server: 4.41.1.1: Creating new disk file /ddbackup/FIP/dump/test3.dmp.S1.dmp.
Backup Server: 4.41.1.1: Creating new disk file /ddbackup/FIP/dump/test3.dmp.S2.dmp.
Backup Server: 4.141.2.87: [11] The 'lockf' call failed for database/archive device while working on stripe device '/ddbackup/FIP/dump/test3.dmp' with error number 37 (No locks available). Refer to your operating system documentation for further details.
Backup Server: 6.53.1.1: OPERATOR: Volume on device '/ddbackup/FIP/dump/test3.dmp' cannot be opened for write access. Mount another volume.
Backup Server: 6.78.1.1: EXECUTE sp_volchanged
        @session_id = 29,
        @devname = '/ddbackup/FIP/dump/test3.dmp',
        @action = { 'PROCEED' | 'RETRY' | 'ABORT' },
        @bs_name = { NULL | 'FIP_BS' }
Backup Server: 4.141.2.87: [11] The 'lockf' call failed for database/archive device while working on stripe device '/ddbackup/FIP/dump/test3.dmp.S2.dmp' with error number 37 (No locks available). Refer to your operating system documentation for further details.
Backup Server: 6.53.1.1: OPERATOR: Volume on device '/ddbackup/FIP/dump/test3.dmp.S2.dmp' cannot be opened for write access. Mount another volume.
Backup Server: 6.78.1.1: EXECUTE sp_volchanged
        @session_id = 29,
        @devname = '/ddbackup/FIP/dump/test3.dmp.S2.dmp',
        @action = { 'PROCEED' | 'RETRY' | 'ABORT' },
        @bs_name = { NULL | 'FIP_BS' }
Backup Server: 4.141.2.87: [11] The 'lockf' call failed for database/archive device while working on stripe device '/ddbackup/FIP/dump/test3.dmp.S1.dmp' with error number 37 (No locks available). Refer to your operating system documentation for further details.
Backup Server: 6.53.1.1: OPERATOR: Volume on device '/ddbackup/FIP/dump/test3.dmp.S1.dmp' cannot be opened for write access. Mount another volume.
Backup Server: 6.78.1.1: EXECUTE sp_volchanged
        @session_id = 29,
        @devname = '/ddbackup/FIP/dump/test3.dmp.S1.dmp',
        @action = { 'PROCEED' | 'RETRY' | 'ABORT' },
        @bs_name = { NULL | 'FIP_BS' }
```

Things I tried to resolve the issue:

- Tried to database dump without stripe on
- Restart the nfslock service
- Dump database to a different FS - WORKING. So I guess I only have
  issues with the NFS
- Restart BS

Appreciate your help on this. Thanks

Comment: Stackoverflow is intended to be a programming resource.  This question is more server/infrastructure related.  [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com) is the better location for this question.  Also, check the answers on this question to see if they might steer you in the right direction: http://serverfault.com/questions/61594/what-does-no-locks-available-mean

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to share that this was resolve by using a mount option in the nfs (per our sysad).